# How to calculate the remaining working days in a month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

I have =INT(B8-NOW())currently running in a cell to show me the remaining days in the month (B8 being a date)

I want to know if there is a way that the output number can calculate only working days, currently showing me just the remaining days. I have tried to search here for a similar question but can't see any.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

These functions already exist in google sheets and excel to accomplish this exact problem:

```
Networkdays and Eomonth
```

You will use eomonth to specify the last day of the month in the second parameter of networkdays and also networkdays has an optional third parameter for a table of holidays

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CodeCamper! You may also be interested in NETWORKDAYS.INTL that gives you some more options about which are the working days and weekends
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902